# iPhone7 (ios 11.1.2) failed to connect to Macbook pro (10.13.6) with error msg "Installation Failed"

Tags: iphone, itunes

iPhone7 (ios 11.1.2) failed to connect to Macbook pro (MacOS 10.13.6) with error msg "Installation Failed"

Basically, I am having the error which is the same as https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8464414.

Anyone have any ideas how to fix it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: what about Just be sure date and time preferences in both your macbook/imac and iphone/ipad are synched.

Comment: @Buscar웃 I have followed all the suggestions in that long discussion thread. No luck. Both date and time are set `automatically` and having the same time zone. (I really don't think anyone in the world will untick the automatically checkbox. I don't know how can macbook and iphone date/time are not synched?) Thank you very much for your reply.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Actually, I didn't follow all the suggestions in that long discussion. After reading all 6 pages roughly, I read it again carefully and tried those suggestions one by one, finally, after using the right hand side USB port instead of left hand side USB port, it works. This is suggested by one person and no one marked it as `Helpful`. This is just very weird. Both USB ports work fine with my external USB Harddrive. And this guy is having trouble with left USB port too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following one suggestion from the [discussion](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8464414):

> I had the same problem when connecting iPad Pro (iOS 12.01) to a MacBook Pro (OS X 10.13.6). Changing the lightning cable did not help. Then I connected the lightning cable to the USB port on the HDMI port side of the notebook and everything worked just fine. I suspect that there is a problem with the USB port on the left hand side of the machine

So everything works after I use the right hand side USB port instead of the left hand side. I have no ideas why. My left hand side USB port is working fine with my USB external drive and all other USB devices I ever used with this macbook.

This is just weird to me.